# mysql_fetch_array with while loop to echo list of URLs

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a list of urls that I need to echo from my "menu" table. Here is what I have so far, but I can't seem to figure out the rest of it. The urls below are obviously there to show the format of the original HTML.

```
<?php

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE level='$level'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

    ?>
        <li><a href="http://website.com/webservices/admin/achievments.php" target="ifrm">Achievments</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://website.com/webservices/admin/avatar.php" target="ifrm">Avatar</a></li>

.... more urls ....
```

Comment: could you show us the table structure

Comment: I'm pretty sure they were all correct. nomaD's answer was most comfortable for me. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in a loop, usually a while loop:

```
<?php

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE level='$level'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo'<li><a href="'.$row['uri'].'" target="ifrm">'.$row['name'].'</a></li>';
}
?>
```

I've improvised on your column names (`uri` and `name`), they will probably be something different.

Answer (score 0):

Close. Personally I would use put it into a while loop to read all the values. then echo them one by one.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
echo "<a href = \"". $row['fieldtouse'] . "\" />". $row['textforlink'] . "<a/>";
}
```

That is the idea. Loop through results. echo results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a simple case of iterating over the result list. And as you already mentioned you should not use a single `mysql_fetch_array`, but in a loop like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

    print "<li><a href='.../$row[0]' target='evil'>$row[1]</a></li>";

}
```

Now $row[0] and $row[1] will have to be adapted. Prefer [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) to get named result columns, and then apply e.g. `$row[url]` and `$row[title]` instead of the numeric keys.